# How to save one-to-many in hibernate/jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Not sure if I described one-to-many relationship with JPA right. 
I have 3 tables: 
Handyman table contains name, address, phone number etc.
Company table has : Company name, address, phone number etc.
WorkOrder table: workOrder number, job site address, FK to handyman's ID, FK to company's ID.
When adding new workorder I use select to pick company and handyman names from database, then fill the workorder form.
The question is how to save it now?

**Handyman.java**

```
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="Handymans_list_id")
private Set<WorkOrder> workOrders;
public Set<WorkOrder> getWorkOrders() {
    return workOrders;
}
public void setWorkOrders(Set<WorkOrder> workOrders) {
    this.workOrders = workOrders;
}
```

**Company.java**

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="Companys_list_id")
private Set<WorkOrder> workOrders;
public Set<WorkOrder> getWorkOrders() {
    return workOrders;
}
public void setWorkOrders(Set<WorkOrder> workOrders) {
    this.workOrders = workOrders;
}
```

**WorkOrder.java**

```
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="Companys_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
//@ManyToOne  
//@JoinColumn(name = "Companys_list_id")
private Company company;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="Handymans_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")

//@ManyToOne  
//@JoinColumn(name = "Handymans_list_id") 
private Handyman handyman;
```

**WorkOrderDAOHibernate.java**

```
    public WorkOrder saveWorkOrder(WorkOrder workOrder)
{
    System.out.println("Open session for saving work order ...");
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session =  sf.openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    //Integer id = (Integer) session.save(workOrder);
    //Company company = workOrder.getCompany();
    //Handyman handyman = new Handyman();
    //String name  = handyman.getHandymanName();
    //System.out.println("Printing company =" + company);
    //System.out.println("Printing handyman = "+ handyman);
    //System.out.println("Handymans name = " + name);

    //

    //workOrder.setCompany(company);

    //workOrder.setHandyman(handyman);
    System.out.println("Workorder "+workOrder);
    Integer id = (Integer) session.save(workOrder);

    trans.commit();
    workOrder.setId(id);
    session.close();
    return workOrder;

}
```

**workorder3.jsp**

```
    <s:form action="resultAction1" namespace="/">

        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.workOrder"      label="Work order number" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.address"        label="Adress/Location" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.email"          label="Email" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.comment"        label="Comment" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.dateReceived"   label="Date receved" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.price"          label="Price" />

<h4>
<s:select label="Pick the company name " 
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Company name"
    list="companyList" 
    name="yourCompanyList" 
     />
</h4> 

<h4>
<s:select label="Pick handyman name " 
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Handyman name"
    list="handymanList" 
    name="yourHandymanList" 
     />
</h4> 


        <s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to define a bi-directional relationship by placing a reference to WorkOrder in HandyMan and Company. In a bi-directional realtionship only one side will be the owner of the relationship. The owner side will have the @JoinColumn annotation and the other side will just have a mappedBy property in the @OneToMany which refers to the bean property that maps the @JoinColumn.

So your class mapping will be as follows:

**Handyman.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="handyman")
private Set<WorkOrder> workOrders;
```

**Company.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="company")
private Set<WorkOrder> workOrders;
```

And in **WorkOrder.java**

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="Companys_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Company company;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="Handymans_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Handyman handyman;
```

**When Saving**:

```
HandyMan handyMan = new HandyMan();
handyMan.setId() // Set the selected id.

Company company = new Company();
company.setId() // Set the selected company id.

workOrder.setCompany(company);
workOrder.setHandyMan(handyMan);

// Populate other details of work order and save using hibernate api.
```